# Space formed by dot products of three vectors

Tags: vectors, geometry

Suppose I have 3 3D unit vectors $\mathbf{v}_1$, $\mathbf{v}_2$, and $\mathbf{V}$. I define the three corresponding scalars $u_1=\mathbf{v}_1 \cdot \mathbf{V}$,  $u_2=\mathbf{v}_2 \cdot \mathbf{V}$, and $U=\mathbf{v}_1 \cdot \mathbf{v}_2$, where obviously each take on values between -1 and 1. However, the range of each value is restricted by the other two, so the shape of the volume available to the system is quite strange.

I'm interested in constructing functions of $u_1$, $u_2$, and $U$ that can only take on values between 0 and 1. To do that, it would be very useful to know more about this volume. Does anyone know if there is some existing work on this, or a useful search term? Failing that, is there a simple inequality that describes the allowed values of $u_1$, $u_2$, and $U$?

Comment: I assume there is a typo and you mean $u_2 = v_2 \cdot V$. And why not use $v_3$ as your third vector? The three dot products you are talking about are the cosines of the angles between the pairs of vectors; I see no geometrical reason why these need to be at all constrained (draw two vectors, you can draw a third vector that has an arbitrary angle to each of the first two). Am I missing some subtle point?

Comment: Good catch on the typo. If you draw two vectors, the third vector can't in general have an arbitrary angle to each of the first two. Consider the case that $u_1=u_2=1$ - $U$ must also be 1.

Comment: When $u_1 = u_2 = 1$, there aren't really three vectors... there is only one since they are all aligned. That does make it a special case.

Comment: It isn't a special case, only a limiting one. If they are each slightly less than 1, $U$ is restricted to values near 1 as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had misread the point of the question - you are asking about limits on the third dot product as a function of the other two dot products...

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Maybe. Definitely not a homework problem, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permit me the liberty of renaming your variables. We will consider three unit vectors $u$, $v$, and $w$, whose inner products are $u \cdot v = c$, $u \cdot w = b$, and $v \cdot w = a$.

Consider the [Gram matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of the vectors $u$, $v$, and $w$, namely the matrix of dot products
$$G =
\begin{bmatrix}
u \cdot u & u \cdot v & u \cdot w \\
v \cdot u & v \cdot v & v \cdot w \\
w \cdot u & w \cdot v & w \cdot w
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & c & b \\ c & 1 & a \\ b & a & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
A symmetric matrix $G$ is a Gram matrix if and only if it is positive semidefinite. Positive semidefiniteness is equivalent to the nonnegativity of all principal minors,
$$
1 - a^2 \ge 0, \\
1 - b^2 \ge 0, \\
1 - c^2 \ge 0, \\
1 - a^2 - b^2 - c^2 + 2 abc \ge 0.
$$
These are the conditions that define the volume you are interested in.

The shape looks like an inflated tetrahedron, all of whose axis-aligned slices are ellipses:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turned out not to be too hard to answer this after all. I found the following inequality:

$$u_1 u_2 - \sqrt{(1-u_1^2)(1-u_2^2)} \le U \le u_1 u_2 + \sqrt{(1-u_1^2)(1-u_2^2)}$$

This can be found by setting $\mathbf{V}=\{0,0,1\}$ and writing the other two vectors as

$$\mathbf{v}_i = \{\sin{\theta_i}\cos{\theta_i}\,,\, \sin{\theta_i}\sin{\theta_i}\,,\, \cos{\theta_i}\}$$

Comment: Happy you figured it out.